# Что означает "cache on-demand"?

Tags: java, кэширование, терминология

Что означает "кэширование по принципу on-demand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кэширование по требованию означает, что данные грузятся в кэш в случае промаха. В противоположность этому есть упреждающее кэширование -- когда данные подгружаются заранее.